# Jump within verbatim block with label

Tags: opcode, yul

I want to inject verbatim block to my yul contract.
My verbatim block is a function, I need to implement if block, to be able to implement it, I need to have ability to use labels, I need to point to offset in code, but in moment I write code I can't hardcode it. It should be way to mark jumpdest with some label, and use jump with this label. Is this possible todo somehow?

Comment: You cannot use labels in verbatim blocks as far as I know. You could use the PC opcode and compute the jumpdest yourself, though...